# Has anyone successfully installed the php-perl extension?

Tags: php, perl, pecl

I've tried going about this three different ways, none of them have worked. The first:

```
root@TheBad:/usr/local/src/# pecl install perl
Package "perl" Version "1.0.0" does not have REST xml available
install failed
```

Second method: Downloading the tar file and having pecl try to install that:

```
root@TheBad:/usr/local/src/php-perl# wget 'http://pecl.php.net/get/perl-1.0.0.tgz'
root@TheBad:/usr/local/src/php-perl# pecl install perl-1.0.0.tgz 
No release notes found
Parsing of package.xml from file "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download/package.xml" failed
install failed
```

Third method: Extract the tar file, try to install manually:

```
root@TheBad:/usr/local/src/php-perl# tar xf perl-1.0.0.tgz 
root@TheBad:/usr/local/src/php-perl# cd perl-1.0.0/
root@TheBad:/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0# phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
root@TheBad:/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0# ./configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
.......(configures successfully)
root@TheBad:/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0# make install
/bin/bash /usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/include -I/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/main -I/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE  -c /usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c -o php_perl.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/include -I/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/main -I/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE -c /usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_perl.o
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:172: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:173: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:199: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:200: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_zval_to_sv_ref’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:343: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘is_ref’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:350: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘is_ref’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_zval_to_sv_noref’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:393: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘is_ref’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:423: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘is_ref’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_sv_to_zval_ref’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:483: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘is_ref’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:485: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_sv_to_zval_noref’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:511: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘Perl_sv_2pv_flags’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE/proto.h:3039: note: expected ‘STRLEN *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:558: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned int’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_call_method’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:651: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘Perl_sv_2pv_flags’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE/proto.h:3039: note: expected ‘STRLEN *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_call’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:714: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘Perl_sv_2pv_flags’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE/proto.h:3039: note: expected ‘STRLEN *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_get’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:753: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_read_dimension’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:827: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:828: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘is_ref’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:836: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_read_property’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:976: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:993: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:1010: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:1088: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:1089: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘is_ref’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:1096: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_clone’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:1637: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned int’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘php_perl_get_iterator’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:1758: error: ‘zval’ has no member named ‘refcount’
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘zm_startup_perl’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:1779: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘zm_info_perl’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:1805: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘v’ in format
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c: In function ‘zim_Perl_eval’:
/usr/local/src/php-perl/perl-1.0.0/php_perl.c:1867: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘Perl_sv_2pv_flags’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE/proto.h:3039: note: expected ‘STRLEN *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
make: *** [php_perl.lo] Error 1
```

I've looked online for solutions to all of these problems, but haven't found anything substantial. Has anyone worked through this problem before, or has any idea what's wrong?

Edit:
Here's version info for my programs, in case any of this matters:
Kernel - 2.6.32-27-generic
GCC - 4.4.3
PEAR - 1.9.0
PHP - 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.5
Zend - 2.3.0

Comment: It seems that the first and second installation methods (using pecl) are failing for a lot of people, so it is probably not a package maintainer's end, making the real question why the manual installation is not working. See http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16807 for more details.

Comment: mind to move your question to serverfault.com ?

Comment: Isn't serverfault more for server-related questions? I guess because we're talking about php this is indirectly a server-related question, but really this is a software question. I don't really mind, I'm just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is newer source here:

http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/perl/trunk/

which was never packed up into the PECL package for some reason.

PECL package: 2006-02-13

Source code: 2009-10-06

Try downloading php_perl.c from here:

http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/perl/trunk/php_perl.c?view=co

drop it in where you're compiling and then try another manual re-compile.

Note that this module could be described as "unstable".

---

Also: download php_perl.h from the same repository:

http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/perl/trunk/php_perl.h?view=co

Then compiling works.

Answer (score 4):

Manage to get Pecl Perl Module installation success

I'll explain in Unix Flavor (Mac OS X Lion)

- Install `Xcode` (for compiler) and as it will also install php source file
- Install `Macports` to install `re2c` package
- run command to create symlinks from php source to `/usr/include`

  sudo ln -s /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include /usr/include
- Download PECL PERL pakckage
- Download php_perl.c from PECL SVN and overwrite the previous downloaded php_perl.c
- cd into the folder
- vi php_perl.h and add

  ```
  #define PHP_PERL_VERSION 0
  ```

before the end of #endif

- run these command

  ```
  sudo phpize
  ./configure --with-perl=/usr/bin/perl --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
  sudo make
  sudo make install
  ```

edit php.ini to add a perl extension at the dynamic extension part

```
extension=perl.so
```

bear in mind that in Mac OS Lion, the .so item will go into folde

```
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
```

restart apache and try again your `phpinfo()`;